# How to pass parameters from suitelet to schedule script on button click: Suitescript 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

i have a suitelet form created in Suitescript 1.0 and it has a button. I want to pass parameters from this suitelet to a schedule script on button click.

How can I do this.
Code snippet will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nlapiScheduleScript()` function accepts script parameters as it's the third argument.

```
var params = {
  custscript_field1: 'Field 1 Value',
  custscript_field2: 'Field 2 Value',
};
nlapiScheduleScript('customscript_scriptid', 'customdeploy_deployid', params);
```

Note that this API is not available client side, so your button will need to call the Suitelet to trigger the Scheduled Script. Additionally, the Suitelet must run with Administrator permissions.

For further details, see the Help Center topics "[SuiteScript 1.0 Creating Script Parameters (Custom Fields)](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=part_N2999210.html)" and "[Scheduling APIs](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3053136.html)".

Comment: I did the thing as you mentioned.

But when it came to retriving those parameters in Scheduled script I am getting **blank Value**.

First the snippet for Suitelet code:
     `var params = {param2: "99", param1: "102"};
 nlapiScheduleScript(209, "customdeploy1", params);`

This is the snippet for the schedule script where I am trying to get the values of this params

  `var p1 = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', param1);
     var p2 = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', param2);`
Gives me a blank value

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to simply add this as a comment. michoel's response is correct for passing parameters into your scheduled script, however the script record for your scheduled script must have these parameter fields created in order for them to be utilized. In order to create these you will need to navigate to your Scheduled Script Record (not the deployment), click on the Parameters Subtab, and then click New Parameter. This brings you to a screen much like that of creating a new custom field. You will give the field a name, an id (note that NetSuite will append custparam in front of whatever you put here), and a Type. Once that is completed you can pass parameters into these fields by referencing the script parameters internal ID. Hope that gets you going in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using below code in Suitelet:

var params = {
  custscript_field1: 'Field 1 Value',
  custscript_field2: 'Field 2 Value'
};
nlapiScheduleScript('customscript_scriptid', 'customdeploy_deployid', params);

Now, use this code to retrieve parameters value :

var p1 = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', custscript_field1);

var p2 = nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT', custscript_field2);

Thanks,
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to create the parameters:

```
var params = [];
params.custscript_field1 = Field 1 Value;
params.custscript_field2 = Field 2 Value;

nlapiScheduleScript('customscript_scriptid', 'customdeploy_deployid', params);
```